# I have a problem with importing price from website to Google Sheets

Tags: parsing, google-sheets

[image]How to import price without discount from https://www.ozon.ru/search/?from_global=true&text=BB-2IN1BRUSH to google sheets
I tried =IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='_2DV4 _17o0 _1v1b']") but it doesn't work (B2 is a link to the product
)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ozon.ru/search/?from_global=true&text=BB-2IN1BRUSH","//span[@class='_2DV4 _17o0 _1v1b']")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ozon.ru/search/?from_global=true&text=BB-2IN1BRUSH";"//span[@class='_2DV4 _17o0 _1v1b']")
```

according to your locale : that will give you 2 values 995 ₽ and 299 ₽
[image]

Comment: When I do it I have an error. i added it to post

Comment: Because the result is on 2 rows. Add `=transpose(___your_ formula_____)` . Don't hesitate to post your file.

Comment: It gives me an error https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hD0Hsy3BnQlBfjuzzN29l7P0cOkrLddvW2umjKy2MKI/edit#gid=0

Comment: access denied, please share at least for reading

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hD0Hsy3BnQlBfjuzzN29l7P0cOkrLddvW2umjKy2MKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='_2DV4 _17o0 _1v1b']"))` you will get 2 values side by side